# java.lang.Class instance and method area relation

Tags: java, jvm

Is there any relation between instances of the `java.lang.Class` and the data area of the JVM called "[Method Area](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.5.4)"?

My guess is that an instance of `java.lang.Class` is created when a class is first loaded and at the same time the code of the methods in this particular class are stored in the *Method Area*.

Answer (score 0):

Your guess is right when you load class code, it's data allocated in Method Area.

> The virtual machine extracts information about the type from the
>   binary data and stores the information in the method area.

[A source of quote.](https://www.artima.com/insidejvm/ed2/jvm5.html)